# Django ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to use ModelForm:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Car(models.Model):
    carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.carnumber

class PickForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Model = Car
```

I have checked this and I cannot find my error.  When I call the view in a browser, it gives me the following error:

```
ModelForm has no model class specified
```

I have tested the view that calls the model with simple "foo bar" code at the same URL, but when I try this code, I get the class error above.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It should be `model` instead of `Model`:

```py
class PickForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

Answer (score 12):

my error was because I wrote `meta` instead of `Meta`.

Comment: Yeah sure class Meta not meta

Answer (score 8):

Just do this method your page will run:

```
class PickForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the error occurs because I wrote 
`class META`
instead, it should be
    `class Meta`

Comment: in my case this happend

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error was due to me wirting :

```
models = User
```

instead of :

```
model = User
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class PickForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Model = Car`
```

Here the Model is case sensitive, so use model instead of Model.

so the code becomes

```
class PickForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a copy and past, you have a typo. I would highly recommend you use an IDE or something with error checking. Eclipse is what I use. It will save you a ton of time from little annoyances like this.

```
class PickForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Model = Car`
```

Your typo is right on the end of Car. The little apostrophe thing.

Comment: I am using geany, I will check out Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

see your code in your defined form code area.there may be error either with =,: and meta,Meta .so please look carefully if case sensitive error or any signs over there

Answer (score 0):

I got this error just by writing `model: Comment` instead of `model = Comment` ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

You missed the basic step of registering your model to the admin. Please do that and that should work for you.

In the `admin.py` file of your app add these lines:

```
from yourapp.models import yourmodel
admin.site.register(yourmodel)
```

Here `yourapp` and `yourmodel` needs to be replaced with the correct names for your app and model.